# How to add data-attribute to elements if else?

Tags: jquery

I ask because have not found anywhere a normal working example.. When you scroll the page should work data-active="on" when reverse data-active="off"

```
var winHeight = $(window).height();
    var thisY = $(this);
    var thisY = e.offset().top;

    if (thisY <= (windowHeight * 0.85)) {
       var dataActiveOn = $(this).attr('data-active', 'on');
    }
    else {
        var dataActiveOff = $(this).attr('data-active', 'off');
    }
```

html code:

```
<section class="js-monitor-scroll" data-active="off"></section>
```

Comment: can you add HTML code as well.

Comment: Are you trying to set the data attribute or read it? `.data('active', 'off');` would set it, `.data('active');` would read the value. What you have `var dataActiveOn = $(this).attr('data-active', 'on');` doesn't really make much sense. It's sort of like saying `var a=(b=c)`

Answer (score 0):

Kindly refer to this snippet.

```js
function changeAttr()
{
  console.log($(".js-monitor-scroll").attr("data-active"));
  $(".js-monitor-scroll").attr("data-active", "on");
  console.log($(".js-monitor-scroll").attr("data-active"));
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="js-monitor-scroll" data-active="off"></section>
<button onclick="changeAttr()">Change attribute</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this isntead of what you have done. Much simpler:

`thisY = $(window).scrollTop();`

And also remove the var in if else... Directly execute the .attr method...

Comment: the console gives the error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined(…)"